# How to find $\lim_{x \to 1^-} (x+1) \lfloor \frac{1}{x+1}\rfloor $?

Tags: calculus, limits

find the limits :

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} (x+1) \lfloor \frac{1}{x+1}\rfloor =?$$

---

My try :

$$\lfloor \frac{1}{x+1}\rfloor=\frac{1}{x+1}-p_x \ \ \ : 0\leq p_x <1$$

So we have :

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} (x+1) (\frac{1}{x+1}-p_x) \\= \lim_{x \to 1^-} -(x+1)p_x=!??$$

Now what ?

Comment: Your calculation in "So we have" is incorrect: $(x+1)/(x+1)=1$.

Comment: I dont see what is difficult with this limit. just plugging 1 then you will find 0

Comment: @GuyFsone: quite right. My feeling is a typo, the limit should be to $-1^-$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust me too but I asked the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475146/find-lim-x-to-a-x-a-left-lfloor-frac1x-a-right-rfloor/2475161#2475161

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**.

Note that $\lfloor z \rfloor=0$ for $0\leqslant z<1$. On the other hand,
$$
\frac{1}{1+x}\in[0,1)
$$
for $x>0$ and in particular for $x$ near $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to 1^-} (x+1) \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x+1}\right\rfloor $$

Let ${x = 1-y}$

So our equation is same as

$$\lim_{y \to 0^+} (2-y) \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2-y}\right\rfloor $$

Floor value is $0$. Also value outside floor funtion tends to $2$.

Thus our equation becomes

$2\cdot 0=0$

So answer is $0$.

QED

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ near $1$ let say $$\frac12<x<1 \Longleftrightarrow  -\frac12<x-1<0$$ we have have that

$$ \frac12<x<1 \Longleftrightarrow \frac32<x+1<2  \Longleftrightarrow \frac12 <\frac{1}{x+1} <\frac 23$$

Therefore

$$ \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x+1}\right\rfloor  =0~~~\forall~ \frac12<x<1 $$
That is , 
$$ (x+1)\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x+1}\right\rfloor  =0~~~\forall~ \frac12<x<1 $$
that is 
$$ \color{red}{\lim_{x \to 1^-}(x+1)\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x+1}\right\rfloor  =0}~$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difficulty here. The first factor tends to $2$, and the fraction inside the floor to $\dfrac12$. Hence

$$\lim_{1^-}=\lim_{1^+}=0.$$